# Finding the Order of a group and the Order of each element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, order-theory, cryptography

I am working on a cryptography example problem. The problem is the following:

> For the group $G = \langle \mathbb{Z}_{26}^*, x\rangle$
>
> a) find the order of the group
>
> b) find the order of each element in the group
>
> c) Is the group a cyclic group? Prove the answer and find the generator(s).

So far, I've started on a and b. This is what I have so far:

a) Since $\mathbb{Z}_{26}^*={1,3,5,7,9,11,15,17,19,21,23,25}$; the order of the group is $12$.

b)

$|1| = 1$,

$|3| = 3$,

$|5| = 4$,

$|7| = ?$,

$|9| = 3$,

$|11| = ?$,

$|15| = ?$,

$|17| = 6$,

$|19| = ?$,

$|21| = 4$,

$|23| = 6$,

$|25| = 2$.

I am not sure about a or b. Are $7,11,15,19$ part of the group?

Am I on the right track? Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

(a) is exactly correct; you want exactly those numbers which do not have $2$ or $13$ as factors.

(b) is also correct where you have answered it. Now note that
$$7^2 = 23, 11^2 = 17, 15^2 = 17, 19^2 = 23,$$ so that all of these elements $(7,11,15,19)$ have order $12$ (as all the right-hand sides have order $6$).

Edit: (c) The existence of an element of order $12$ automatically implies that the group is cyclic; for example, the powers of $7$ exhaust the group:
$$1,7,23,5,9,11,25,19,3,21,17,15.$$

Comment: For the elements (7,11,15,19), i'm still a bit confused. How do they have the order 12?

Comment: Because $7^{12} = 11^{12} = 15^{12} = 19^{12} = 1$, and there is no lower number $n$ for which $7^n = 1$ (and $11^n = 1$, and so on)

Answer (score 0):

(a) is right:  Euler's totient function evaluated at $26$ is $\varphi (26)=\varphi (2)\cdot\varphi (13)=(2-1)(13-1)=12$.

For (b), raise each element to powers until you get $1\pmod{26}$.  The smallest such power is the order.

For (c), it is well known that $\mathbb Z_n^*$ is cyclic for $n$ equal to $2$ times a power of an odd prime.  Thus, you will find at least one element of order $12$...  (actually there should be $\varphi(\varphi (26))=4$ such...)